# Как создать ключ авторизации на firebase для приложения?

Tags: android, firebase, keystore

Сгенерировал key.jks для приложения, теперь понадобилось создать ключ авторизации на firebase, ввожу

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias key -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Далее ввожу пароль от файла, но выводит ошибку, в чем проблема?

```
unix@unix-N53SM ~/Документы/Проекты/Android Studio/Key Store $ keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias key.jks -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
Enter keystore password:  
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at     java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
    at     java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1024)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:397)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:390)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, оказывается нужно использовать стандартный ключ, а это androiddebugkey, тогда если ввести

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \ 
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

То все работает